# Optional sampling exercise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

I came across the following exercise in Stochastic Calculus:

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Let also $M$ be the following process:

$M_t=B^4_t-6t(B^2_t-\dfrac{t}{3})$ for $t\geq0$

Prove that $M=(M_t)_{t\geq0}$ is a martingale and if we set $\sigma=inf\{t\geq0 : |B_t|=\sqrt{3}\}$, compute $\mathbb{E}[M_{\sigma}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\sigma^2]$.

It was easy to prove the martingale part. Can we use the Optional Sampling Theorem for $\sigma$ and if so, how can we calculate $\mathbb{E}[\sigma^2]$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{t}{3}$ (in the definiton of $M_t$) is correct? I think it should be $\frac{t}{2}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau := \inf\{t \geq 0; B_t \in (-a,b)^c\}$ where $a,b>0$. Using Wald's identities one can show that $\mathbb{E}\tau = a \cdot b$. Moreover $\mathbb{E}\tau^n<\infty$ for all $n \geq 1$ ([Proof (Exercise 5.16(a))](http://www.motapa.de/brownian_motion/solutions-bm.pdf)). Choose $a=b=\sqrt{3}$, then $\tau=\sigma$. Thus $\sigma \in L^2$, $\sigma \in L^1$, $\mathbb{E}\sigma = \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}=3$. We obtain

$$M_{\sigma}(w) = 3^2 - 6\sigma(w) \cdot \left(3-\frac{\sigma(w)}{2} \right) \\
\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}M_\sigma = 9 - 18 \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\sigma}_{\sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}} + 3 \mathbb{E}(\sigma^2) = 9-18 \cdot 3 +3\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2)$$

On the other hand

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge \sigma}) = \mathbb{E}M_0 = 0$$

by optinal sampling theorem (applied to the stopping time $\sigma \wedge t$). Since

$$|M_{t \wedge \sigma}| \leq 3^2 + 6\sigma \cdot \left(3+\frac{\sigma}{2}\right) \in L^1$$

we have (by dominated convergence) $\mathbb{E}M_\sigma = 0$. This implies

$$\mathbb{E}\sigma^2 =\frac{45}{3}=15$$

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! It's $M_t := B_t^4-6t \cdot \left(B_t^2-\frac{t}{2} \right)$!$\\$

Would it suffice to say that:

$P[-\sqrt{3}<B_t<\sqrt{3}]=P[-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{t}}<\dfrac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}<\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{t}}]=2\Phi(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{t}})-1$ whis is zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$ and so $\sigma$ is almost surely bounded?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{P}[|B_t|<\sqrt{3}] \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ implies only $\mathbb{P}[\sigma<\infty]=1$. As far as I can see $\sigma$ is not necessarily a.s. bounded.

Comment: If so, how can we use the Optional Sampling Theorem? Shoudn't we have that $\mathbb{E}[\sigma]<\infty$ in order to use it?

Sorry for my perhaps naive question but I am a novice and I am trying to clear things out in my head.

Comment: I applied the Optional Sampling Theorem to the stopping time $\sigma \wedge t$ (which is bounded (by $t$)) - this step we could do without knowing $\sigma \in L^1$. But you are right, we need $\sigma \in L^2$, $\sigma \in L^1$ (for the rest of the proof). Here is a [proof (Exercise 5.16)](http://www.motapa.de/brownian_motion/solutions-bm.pdf) (they show $\mathbb{E}\tau^n<\infty$ for all $n \geq 1$ where $\tau := \inf\{t \geq 0; B_t \in (-a,b)^c\}$ ... choose $a=b=\sqrt{3}$, then $\tau=\sigma$ since $B$ has continuous paths.)

Comment: Really nice proof! And it covers every case of a stopping time of this kind! Thank you very much!

If we had the following:

$M_t=B^3_t-B^2_t-3t(B_t-\dfrac{1}{3})$ and we want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[M_\sigma]$ (now, I know how to do it) and $\mathbb{E}[\sigma B_\sigma]$?

How will we treat $B^3_\sigma$?

Comment: To calculate $\mathbb{E}(B_\sigma^3)$ you can use $\mathbb{P}[B_\sigma = -\sqrt{3}] = \mathbb{P}[B_\sigma = \sqrt{3}] = \frac{1}{2}$ (it's also a consequence of Wald's identities).

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[B^3_t]=\mathbb{E}[B^3_t(I_{[B_t=\sqrt{3}]}+I_{[B_t=-\sqrt{3}]})]= \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{3}^3-\sqrt{3}^3]=0$

Is that right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether you understood correctly what you are calculating. $\mathbb{E}(B_\sigma^3) = \mathbb{E}(B_\sigma^3 \cdot (1_{[B_\sigma=\sqrt{3}]}+1_{[B_\sigma=-\sqrt{3}]})) = (\sqrt{3})^3 \cdot 1/2 + (-\sqrt{3})^3 \cdot 1/2 = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, of course... The "measure" (probability) of the indicator function. I just had in mind that the integrals are equal and forgot to count the probability.

Comment: In this case it's fine :) ...

Comment: Btw: Accepting answers is a simple way of thanking the strangers who are helping you out. You can accept an answer by ticking the check-mark next to the one you found most helpful.